# Creating skinned components and UI editor for scaleform

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, user-interface, actionscript, project-management

Our project is a MMORPG, using `scaleform` to render UI. Now we use `Flash CS5` to create UI panels with `scaleform CLIK`. With the development of this project, we encountered some problems:

1. `CLIK` is not skinned, we have to create separate symbols for each component with different disappearance, so we have `PushButton1`, `PushButton2`, `RadioButton1`, `RadioButton2`...
2. `Flash CS5` is not a *What You See is What You Get* tool. For instance, we have a shared component named `Window`, it has a `close` button as it's child. In a `fla`, we first pull a `Window` on the stage, and modify its size, the `close` button will be scaled in the stage.
   We can constrain the `close` button in as code, but artists have to see the right result in `Gfx Player` on runtime.
3. We have some common components `fla` like `common_button.fla` with most of button components in it. Common components are runtime shared in different `fla`. In a UI `fla` (e.g. `friendpanel.fla`), when we need a common component, we copy it from `common_xxx.fla` and paste it in the new `fla` library. If a panel is complex, it's library will be confused and not easily managed. If the common one is not satisfying requirement, we will double-click the pasted component and modify it in the local `fla`, and this caused more resource management troubles.

So I consider if we should create a skinned UI component lib and an UI editor to handle this problems. Does any one has similar experience?

Answer (score 0):

These are common workflow problems reported by many Flash IDE users unfortunately. Certainly, creating your own tool to solve these problems is a good option, but a costly one. The Scaleform team is investigating possible solutions to these types of issues for future versions of the SDK. In the meantime, there's not much that can be done to remedy these issues that I am aware of.